# Detect session/cookie variable in wordpress to prevent access to documents

Tags: php, sql, security, session

Hey guys, I've gotten as far as my code below, but I am trying to create an AJAX search form that is 'safe' on my wordpress blog, by detecting the session variable or a cookie or something

```
<?php
@session_start();

If (!array_key_exists(‘authed’, $_SESSION))
{
     include ‘not_authed.inc’;
     exit();
}

// go about your business.

?>
```

and i'm trying to add that to this:

```
<?php

function checkValues($value)
{
     // Use this function on all those values where you want to check for both sql injection and cross site scripting
     //Trim the value
     $value = trim($value);

    // Stripslashes
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }

     // Convert all &lt;, &gt; etc. to normal html and then strip these
     $value = strtr($value,array_flip(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES)));

     // Strip HTML Tags
     $value = strip_tags($value);

    // Quote the value
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    return $value;

}   
mysql_connect ("mysql.*****.com", "****","$*****")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("***********");

$term = checkValues($_REQUEST['val']);
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($term);

$sql = mysql_query("select * FROM patient_db WHERE id_number = '$term'");


if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<img src=\"******\" class='leftfloat' border=0>";
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<br /> ID Number: '   .$row['id_number'];
    echo '<br /> Name: '        .$row['Name'];
    echo '<br /> Exp. Date: '   .$row['exp_date'];
    echo '<br /> DOB: '         .$row['dob'];
    echo '</p>';
    //echo "<a href='******' title='Printer Friendly Version' alt='Printer Friendly Version'><img src=\"*****\" class='rightfloat' border=0 height=33 width=33></a>";
} else {
    echo "<img src=\"*****\" height=50 width=50 class='leftfloat' border=0>";
    print "<h1>USER ID <br/>NOT FOUND</h1><br />";
    print "<strong>OOPS!! THIS COULD BE AN ERROR</strong><br />";
    print "<br />";
    print "<div>*****</div>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are going to have is that the `AJAX` request is a separate session / cookie as it is a completely different process not tied into to the browser.

So how do you go about authenticating someone? A Token of sorts. So you would create a hash, which would need to be stored in the database for the user, which can be regenerated upon login etc. Then you would use this token to validate that user and allow the AJAX submission to work.

Hopefully that gets the ball rolling for you. So in your AJAX push script you would just appened a variable to the GET or POST data called `token` and then check it on the receiving PHP script. There are other ways of doing it, this is just one that I know of :)